# How to select complete text in a div or input field when user long press on it in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, html

I have been trying for the last 2 days to achieve this.

I am trying to display some text on a div. When the user long presses on a div, the complete text in the div should be selected. As we know mobile devices give context menu on long presses, and users can 'copy' the complete text that was displayed on the div.

I have tried using clipboard.js but could not achieve this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Please note that this is mainly for browsers in Android/iOS

I am very new in using front end technologies but I have gotten the above task to complete.

Comment: post you have already tried

Comment: I have tried in different ways, I used 'taphold' of mobile jquery for longpress event, clipboard.js for copying text to clipboard. And also tried css to select whole text of a div. But nothing helped me to achieve what I am actually looking for.

Please note that I am a beginner in front end technlogies

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to achieve this

```
var longPressTimer = null;

$("div").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(longPressTimer)
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  var LONG_PRESS_TIME = 1000; //this is 1second

  longPressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { 

     //this function will call after one second. you can collect the div data.

  }, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
  return false; 
});
```